# Create record using through association and nested_form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-form-for

The following is my model structure

```
role.rb 

has_many :user_roles 
has_many :users, through: :user_roles 
has_many :companies, through: :user_roles

user.rb

has_one :user_role, dependent: :destroy
has_one :role, through: :user_role
has_one :company, through: :user_role 

company.rb

has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :users, through: :user_roles
has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

user_role.rb

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role, optional: true
belongs_to :company
```

***I want to create record using association and nested form and right now I am able to create Company along with user using nested form, but I also want to create user_role for User.***

I have included `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` in company model.
and used `fields_for` to create user in company new form.

The following is my form

```
<%= form_for @company, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if company.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: :"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :website %>
    <%= f.text_field :website, class: :"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, class: :"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: :"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :company_image %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :users do |builder| %>
    <%= render "users_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: :'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Right now, the user_role is not created when creating the company. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `user_role` is not created, so there must be some sort of error message or reason why it is not created. Include your controller code, include the output of `@company.errors.full_messages` and the check how your parameters are showing up. Maybe the `user_role` is not `saving` because it is not valid. `user_role` has a `belongs_to :user` and a `belongs_to :role, optional: true`. The validation of the presence of `role` will be skipped, but you need to have a valid `user`. If you are giving that `user_role` a `user_id` which belongs to an unsaved user, the validation will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Fabrizio,
I have validate user . 
UserRole is third table for user and company. fields for user_role is user_id, role_id and company_id.
It creating user_role with user_id and company_id, but not including role_id into user_role record.
Please look into strong params 
`params.require(:company).permit(:name, :website, :phone, :description, :company_image, users_attributes: [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :string, :birth_date, :join_date, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation])`

Comment: the `user_role belongs_to user`. `user_role.user_id` must correspond to the `id` of an existing `user`. The field `id` of a row in `users`. If you try to save `user_role` and the `user` has not been already saved, you will trigger a validation error and the `user_role` will not be saved. Save the `user` before creating the `user_role`

Comment: You structured your `db` wrong. `user has_one :role` and `role has_many :users`. You just set the `user.role_id` field when you create the user. No need to create the object, you create in your `seed.rb` file the standard `roles` and if you need you provide functionality to create the `roles` separately. When you create the `user`, you just set the role he will have, not create an object. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @wish  check my solution. It should work for you.Its tested.

Answer (score 1):

> **I want to create record using association and nested form and right now I am able to create Company along with user using nested form, but I also want to create user_role for User.**

Before creating a `user_role` you need to commit and save to the `db` your `user`, otherwise you will run into a validation error.

`user_role` is not saved because the `user_id` you are setting does not correspond to a saved `user`

`user_role` belongs_to user. `user_role.user_id` must correspond to the `id` of an existing `user` (field `id` of a row in `users`). If you try to save `user_role` object and the `user` has not been already saved, you will trigger a validation error and the `user_role` will not be saved. Save the `user` in your controller before creating the `user_role`.

Comment: You did great try but, as I told you before 
> It creating user_role with user_id and company_id, but not including role_id into user_role record. Problem is not with user object issue is to save complete record.

Answer (score 0):

> **MODELS**

***1.company.rb***

```
# put inverse_of otherwise it will throw error. To know more about inverse of go throw docs
has_many :user_roles, inverse_of: :company
has_many :users, through: :user_roles
has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles
```

***2.user_role.rb***

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role
belongs_to :company

# user_roles_attributes will accept nested attributes for both user and role
accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

***3.user.rb***

```
has_many :user_roles#, inverse_of: :user
has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
has_many :company, through: :user_roles
```

***4.role.rb***

```
has_many :user_roles
has_many :users, through: :user_roles
has_many :companies, through: :user_roles
```

> **Companycontroller.rb**

```
def new
    @company = Company.new
    urole = @company.user_roles.build
    urole.build_user
    urole.build_role
end

def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  @company.save
end

private 
def company_params
  # here put associate modal attributes to permit.
  params.require(:company).permit(:company_name,
    user_roles_attributes: [
      role_attributes: [:role_name],
      user_attributes: [:user_name, :email]
    ]
  )
end
```

> ***form.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for @company, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>


  <%=f.fields_for :user_roles do |user_roles_builder| %>

    --USER DETAILS--
    <br>
    <%=user_roles_builder.fields_for :user do | user_builder | %>
      <%= render "users_fields", :f => user_builder %>
    <% end %>
    <br>


    -- ROLE DETAILS--
    <br>
    <%=user_roles_builder.fields_for :role do | role_builder | %>
      <%= render "users_fields", :f => role_builder %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

*Follow this and it should work for you*